# Automapper in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, automapper

I am having a devil of a time attempting to translate the following piece of code from c# to VB.Net.  I have little experience in VB.Net and all my searches have proven fruitless to date.

```
IMapper DataReaderMapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.AddDataReaderMapping();
    cfg.CreateMap<IDataReader, MyDTO1>();
    cfg.CreateMap<IDataReader, MyDTO2>();
    cfg.CreateMap<IDataReader, MyDTO3>();
}).CreateMapper();
```

The code is using the Automapper and Automapper.Data nuget packages to map datatables to DTOs. I know the code works fine in c#.

My best guess was the following:

```
Dim DataReaderMapper As IMapper = New MapperConfiguration(Function(cfg) {cfg.AddDataReaderMapping(), cfg.CreateMap(Of IDataReader, MyDTO1)()}).CreateMapper()
```

The above results in an "Overload resolution failure" warning as I am obviously not passing in the arguments/parameters in the correct fashion/order. I can usually muddle by with most translations that I have to deal with but this one is stumping me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't want the braces, those are block definition in C# which is accomplished in VB by the `Sub` or `Function` and corresponding `End Sub` or `End Function`.  Most likely, it should be a `Sub` rather than a `Function` as it looks like it operates on its argument rather than returning something.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://converter.telerik.com/

```
    Dim DataReaderMapper As IMapper = New MapperConfiguration(Function(cfg)
                                                                  cfg.AddDataReaderMapping()
                                                                  cfg.CreateMap(Of IDataReader, MyDTO1)()
                                                                  cfg.CreateMap(Of IDataReader, MyDTO2)()
                                                                  cfg.CreateMap(Of IDataReader, MyDTO3)()
                                                              End Function).CreateMapper()
```

Comment: As I noted in my comment, I think it's more likely to be a `Sub` than a `Function` because it doesn't return anything.

Comment: This code comes from the converter(telerik). A function that doesn't return anything *is* a Sub.

Comment: That is not correct.  Try it under `Option Strict` and see.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve by combining the responses of Nick Abbot's Telerik conversion and Craig's suggestion to swap out "Function" for "Sub" to get the following:

```
Dim DataReaderMapper As IMapper = New MapperConfiguration(Sub(cfg)
                                                              cfg.AddDataReaderMapping()
                                                              cfg.CreateMap(Of IDataReader, MyDTO1)()
                                                              cfg.CreateMap(Of IDataReader, MyDTO2)()
                                                              cfg.CreateMap(Of IDataReader, MyDTO3)()
                                                          End Sub).CreateMapper()
```